# How to hide jTable at jFrame

Tags: java, jtable, jframe

How to hide `jTable` at `jFrame` in java GUI, not just hide the column, but entire `jTable`?

I was try to use `table.setVisible(false)`, but just hide a column not entire table

Comment: table.setVisible(false) is fine. Show us your code to check where the problem might be

Comment: Also consider `CardLayout`.

Answer (score 4):

You cannot hide the table, but you can hide your panel containing the table
instead.

`yourPanel.setVisible(false);`

Whenever you want to show the table do `yourPanel.setVisible(true);`

Comment: if you hide the jPanel the jFrame is decreased in size and once you set it as visible you need to increase the window size to make it appear. Any solution on this?